# Find all triples $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R} : ab + c = bc + a = ca + b = 4$

Tags: number-theory

Any help on this question would be great. Ive found that (1,1,3), (3,1,1), (1,3,1) but am confused on how to find more anymore (if there are any).Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't forget the two solutions with $a=b=c$.

Comment: $a=b=c$ gives $a^2+a-4=0$, which has no integral roots. So we get new solutions (all solutions above are integer solutions).

Comment: @DietrichBurde  Did you mean to say $a^2 + a -4 = 0$ has no integral roots? or that $a^2+a-4$ has non-integral roots?  "no integral roots" $\not \implies $ "new solutions".  Which is easy to interpret as "no solutions".  Which is *not* the case as we *do* what all *real* solutions.

Answer (score 3):

If $ab+c=bc+a$ then $ab-bc+c-a=0$ that is $(a-c)(b-1)=0$.
Thus $a=c$ or $b=1$. Similarly $a=b$ or $c=1$. Also $b=c$ or $a=1$.
Combining these we get various cases to consider. For instance,
if $a=c$ and $a=b$ then $4=a^2+a$ etc. Or if $a=c$ and $c=1$ then
$4=ac+b=1+b$ so $b=3$ etc.

Comment: What is $s$ in $4=s^2+a$? You probably mean $a^2+a=4$.

Comment: Nice! For the final case analysis, it's perhaps more elegant to start by observing that $a=b=c=1$ is _not_ a solution, so at least one of the numbers must be different from $1$. Therefore the two other numbers are equal, and the only cases to consider are then whether their common value is $1$ or not.

Answer (score 2):

If $a b+c=4$ then $a=\frac{4-c}{b}$ assuming that $b\not=0$ and then $b c+a =4$ which is $b c+\frac{4-c}{b}=4$ so $c(b-\frac{1}{b})+\frac{4}{b} = 4$ so $c= \frac{4-\frac{4}{b}} { b-\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{4}{b+1}$ assuming that $b\not -1,1$ and to the final equation we get that $c a+b=4$ which is $c(\frac{4-c}{b})+b=4$ which is $\frac{4}{b+1}(\frac{4-\frac{4}{b+1}}{b})+b=4$ and solving for $b$ we get that $b=3,\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{17})$ so $c=1,\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{17})$ and $a=1,\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{17})$ so the only solutions are :

$(1,3,1)$ and all its permutations and $(\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1+\sqrt{17})),(\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{17}),\frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{17}))$

Answer (score 2):

$ab + c = bc + a = ca + b=4$

By symmetry any solution for any any one of $a,b,c$ can be a solution for any other.

$ab +c = bc +a$ means $ab - bc = b(a-c) = a-c$  So either $b=1$ or $a=c$.

So by symmetry:

if $a\ne 1$ then $b=c$ and if $b\ne 1$ then $a = c = b$.  So it is not possible that only one of $a,b,c$ is equal to $1$.

So either:

1) All $a,b,c$ equal $1$

2) None of $a,b,c$ equal $1$ and $a=b=c$.

3) Two of $a,b,c$ equal $1$ and the third does not.

....

1) $1*1 + 1 = 4$ is not possible.

2)we get $a^2 + a = 4$ and $a = \frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$.

3) wolog $a= b = 1$ so $1 + c = c + 1 = c + 1 = 4$.  $c = 3$.

So there are 5 solutions:

And $(a,b,c) = (1,1,3)$, $(1,3,1)$ , $(3,1,1), ( \frac {-1+ \sqrt{17}}2,\frac {-1+ \sqrt{17}}2,\frac {-1+ \sqrt{17}}2)$ or $ ( \frac {-1- \sqrt{17}}2,\frac {-1- \sqrt{17}}2,\frac {-1- \sqrt{17}}2)$